# Getting list of properties of a DataType from current page

Tags: c#, umbraco, umbraco8

Good evening!

I am currently working on the backend of my application and I need to get a list of all properties of a certain datatype but only the ones in the current page.

`listFiltersCms = _umbraco.ContentAtRoot().SelectMany(c => c.Descendants<DataFilters>()).ToList();`

This line above gathers all the filters from all the pages, but I want the filters from a specific page (can be currentPage).

I have tried something like this:

`var listFiltersCms = _umbraco.AssignedContentItem.SelectMany(c => c.Descendants<DataFilter>()).ToList();`

But without any luck :( Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you mean by "the backend of my application" - are you inside Umbraco or on a public website?

I ask because there is a fairly straightforward way of getting all info on a specific datatype, but it is not really meant to be used on public facing websites. It *can* be, but it might be taxing on the system as I believe it queries the database directly, which is not ideal.

Anyway, you might want to take a look at the DataTypeService:
https://our.umbraco.com/Documentation/Reference/Management/Services/DataTypeService/Index-v8

And here you can see what options you have for using it (not very explanatory, but I spot a few methods you could probably look into):
https://our.umbraco.com/apidocs/v8/csharp/api/Umbraco.Core.Services.IDataTypeService.html

If you decide to use the service in a scenario where there will be a lot of requests, maybe consider caching the output to spare the database.

Comment: What I mean with backend is basically the solution that is using the umbraco content, where I have the models, an API and such. I even have the modes done for each datatype that I require but I can only get all of the same datatype if I get them from the root.

Comment: So ... you're not really after all options in a datatype, but you need the value of a property on a current page? How about just Model.[yourPropertyNameWithoutBrackets] or even Model.Value("yourPropertyName") - what does that return? https://our.umbraco.com/Documentation/Fundamentals/Design/Rendering-Content/index-v8

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this issue was by getting the page in the correct model. In my case all I had to do was:
(_umbraco.AssignedContentItem as PageModel).FilterCustomMeasures;